# JavaFX:функция записи данных из файла в текстовую область (TextArea), удаление данных из нее, сохранение данных из текстовой области

Tags: java, javafx

Помогите пожалуйста правильно написать функции чтения данных из файла в TextArea, удаление данных из нее, а так же сохранeние данных TextArea в файл! 
Код программы :

```
package ch.makery.address.view;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

import ch.makery.address.MainApp;
import ch.makery.address.PrepodMainApp;
import ch.makery.address.model.GhurnalOcenok;
import ch.makery.address.model.Lections;
import ch.makery.address.model.Test;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

public class LectionsController {

        @FXML
        public TextArea taLection;
        @FXML
        private Button butOpen;//save
        @FXML
        private Button butSave;//look
        @FXML
        private Button butUdalit;//udalit

        /**
         * The constructor.
         * The constructor is called before the initialize() method.
         */
        public LectionsController() {
        }

        public void FileOpen(){
               JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();
               fileopen.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
                int ret = fileopen.showDialog(null, "Открыть файл");                
                if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = fileopen.getSelectedFile();
                    try {
                        FileRead(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                    }
              }
           }

           public void FileSave(){
               JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();
               fileopen.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
                int ret = fileopen.showDialog(null, "Сохранить в файл");                
                if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = fileopen.getSelectedFile();
                    try {
                        FileWrite(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                    }
                }
            }

           public void Delete(){
                if(PrepodMainApp.getLectionList().size()>0){

                  taLection.clear();
                }
            }

               public void FileWrite(String Filename)throws IOException{
                    FileWriter f = new FileWriter(Filename);

                    for(Lections tst : PrepodMainApp.getLectionList()){

                        f.write(tst.Lecii.getValue() + "\r\n");
                    }

                    f.close();
                }

               public void FileRead(String Filename) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{         
                   PrepodMainApp.getLectionList().clear();          

                    Scanner fin = new Scanner(new File(Filename));  
                    String test;

                    while(fin.hasNext())
                    {
                        if(PrepodMainApp.getLectionList().size()>0){
                            fin.nextLine();
                        }

                        test = fin.nextLine();



                          PrepodMainApp.getLectionList().add(new Lections(
                                  new SimpleStringProperty(test) ));

                    }       
                    fin.close();    

                }


}
```

[image: 232]

Comment: В каком месте ошибка? П.С. используете javaFX - не используйте контролы из свинга ( например, JFileChooser, в javafx есть аналог)

Comment: Ошибка логическая : при нажатии соответствующих кнопок (см рисунок)--  считывание, удаление и запись не происходит. Не знаю как правильно описать эти функции для текстовой области.

Comment: А вы обработчики повесили на кнопки?

Answer (score 1):

Сам код

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
    import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;


    public class Main extends Application {
TextArea text;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        text = new TextArea();
        root.setRight(text);            

        Button btnRead = new Button("Read");
        Button btnClear = new Button("Clear");
        Button btnWrite = new Button("Write");
        GridPane noRoot = new GridPane();
        noRoot.add(btnWrite, 0, 0);
        noRoot.add(btnClear, 0, 1);
        noRoot.add(btnRead, 0, 2);
        root.setCenter(noRoot);

        btnRead.setOnAction(new ReadButton());
        btnClear.setOnAction(new ClearButton());
        btnWrite.setOnAction(new WriteButton());        

        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
public List<String> read(){
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    FileChooser choose = new FileChooser();
    File txt = choose.showOpenDialog(null);
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner (txt)){
        while(in.hasNext()){
            list.add(in.nextLine());

        }

    }catch(IOException ex){            
           System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
           }

    return list;
}

private class ReadButton implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
        text.setText(read().toString());

    }
}
private class ClearButton implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
        text.clear();

    }
}
private class WriteButton implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{


    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        File file = new File("test");
        try (FileOutputStream filtrom = new FileOutputStream(file); 
                ObjectOutputStream objektstrom = new ObjectOutputStream(filtrom)) { 
            String res = text.getText();
            objektstrom.writeObject(res);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("не удалось создать файл " + file.getName());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Проблема с записью в файл " + file.getName());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

}

полностью рабочий код. Доработать под ваши пожелания немного)
при чтении использовал Scanner. Не всегда удобоваримая штука можно использовать вот так и возможные исключения докинул.

```
    public static String ReadButton(){
   try (FileInputStream filstrom = new FileInputStream(file);
            ObjectInputStream objektstrom = new ObjectInputStream(filstrom)) {

        innObjekt = objektstrom.readObject();           
        if (innObjekt instanceof [...]) {
            resultat = ([...])innlestObjekt;
            Object objekt = resultat;
            if (!(objekt instanceof [...])) {
                System.err.println("Ошибка типа объекта");
                return null;
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Файл не готов  " + file.getName());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Проблема с чтением файла " + file.getName());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Fila " + file.getName() + " содержит не известный объект класса");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultat;
}
```

}